# CSS and JS not detecting by nginx - server responds with a status of 404

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

this is my nginx.conf. CSS and JS are in this folder

```html
/usr/share/nginx/static/css
/usr/share/nginx/static/js
/usr/share/nginx/static/media
```

```html
location ~ (css|js|img) {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location / {

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

but I am getting this error

```html
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                               2.0fe3a37f.chunk.css:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                               2.0a7ada56.chunk.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                               main.e5e7c1e6.chunk.css:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                               main.8a3eed81.chunk.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                               2.0a7ada56.chunk.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                               main.8a3eed81.chunk.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                               2.0fe3a37f.chunk.css:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                               main.e5e7c1e6.chunk.css:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                               main.e5e7c1e6.chunk.css:1
```

Comment: Try with `root /usr/share/nginx/static;`

Comment: I tried like this but does not work

```
location ~ (css|js|img) {

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/static;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location / {

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
```

Comment: What entries are in the access log?

Comment: yep thanks I checked the access log and it takes a different path.. probably path is hard-coded somewhere I guess. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and only following helped to me (I used FastApi project and deploy it on AWS EC2 server):

root path taken from following info (just copy this command to your terminal):

```
            nginx -V 2>&1 | grep --color -o -e '--prefix=[^[:space:]]\+'
```

add root path, which got from info above, to nginx.conf:

```
            location /      {
                            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                            root /usr/share/nginx;
            }
```

in html path to css:

```
            <link href="/static/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
```